# Smallest vectorial space generated by a part $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a subset $A$ inside a vectorial space $E$.

We call $Vect(A)$ the smallest vectorial space containing $A$ included in $E$.

I defined it as $Vect(A)=\{x ~/ x=\lambda a, \lambda \in \mathbb{K}, a \in A \}$

But it doesn't work if $A=\varnothing$

My question is thus :

Is my definition true for any other part than $\varnothing$ or there is something wrong in what I wrote ? (Is the case $\varnothing$ the only exception where my definition isn't true).

Comment: It doesn't work if $|A|\ge 2$ either.

Comment: Yes you are right. I understood my problem thanks.